# share volume with existing container

Tags: docker, docker-machine

i am new to docker. i want to share a volume with multiple containers which are existing previously in my local pc not in the docker hub.
when i am using the command "**sudo docker run -i -t --mount source=volume,target=/volume-shared ubuntu20**", this is coming error as below.

**Unable to find image 'ubuntu20:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ubuntu20, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.**

here ubuntu20 is the container name.

can anyone help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the syntax you've used, `ubuntu20` is an _image_ name.  Do you mean `ubuntu:20.04`?  Or do you need to delete and recreate your existing container?

Comment: yes the image name i changed to ubuntu20.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create volume with mount point on folder you want, and then just mount volume to container.
Check this:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/